# Django - Pass Form data in URL

Tags: django

I want to pass the forms data to another view (if possibleby GET params)

```
def post(self, request):
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = HttpResponse(reverse('page_to_go'))
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. "pass form data to another view" doesn't really mean anything, in part because you don't tell us what the "other" view is. To clarify this, step back from the code for a minute and describe in words what your user will see. I assume you have a web page with a form where the user can enter some information. What are the fields on this form? What should happen when the user clicks the Submit button? What page should load next?

Comment: I have a table showing all the users, and I am using a modal form that contains the filters of the table (i.e. filter by active users, filter by role ) 

The table is updated dynamically if a trigger is fired, using HTMX.
For the modal to be hidden I need to send an Http Response 204 (hides the modal), along with the HX-Trigger (to re-renders the table)

Comment: The case I am trying to solve is: The modal when its submitted, should call a function that returns an HttpResponse with status code 204 and the content of the form in the modal, should be passed on to the ListView to perform the filtering  and the update of the table.

Comment: I can imagine I am probably taking a "wrong thinking path" of how I am approaching the problem, therefore any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't) call a view function directly. Instead, do as Alireza Raei suggests in their answer below and move any logic that is used by two or more views to a separate function that each view can call.